# Convergence of partial sums of real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

For all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, let $(a_{i,n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence that tends to $0$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$. It holds also that $|a_{i,n}|\leq1$ for all $i,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to show that \begin{align*} 
c_n:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i,n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0?\end{align*} Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counter-example:
$$a_{i,n}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1&n< 2i\\0 & n\ge  2i\end{array}\right.\ .$$
It is easy to see that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Can you expand on your "easy to see" statement? Unless I am much mistaken, this sequence has no limit, and is a canonical example of such a sequence...

Comment: @user1729: Can you evaluate $c_n$ using the definitions?

Comment: Oh, sorry, had miss-read what you wrote.

Comment: @user1729: Please never mind. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer!

Comment: @stroem: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

- $ a_{i,n} ≤ 1 $
- $ ∑a_{i,n} ≤ n $
- $ (∑a_{i,n}) /n ≤ 1 $
- $ lim(∑a_{i,n}/n) \rightarrow0$

finaly $C_n \rightarrow0$

Comment: I do not understand when you say "$C_{n+1} = C_n + \delta(n)\rightarrow0$ but not to $0$." Two $0$s?

Comment: :) thanks user1729 I don't know how to write math on internet. I mean delta(n) ->0  not Cn+delta(n) please help me for editing lol

Comment: Click on "edit" to see what I did. It is LaTeX. There is a tutorial page [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Basically, wrap everything in dollar signs, sub-scripts are "_" while super-scripts (powers) are "^". Use the curly brackets "{" and "}" to group symbols together when applying sub- and super-scripts. So, for example, $e^{i\pi}$ is given by e^{i\pi} rather than e^i\pi or e^(i\pi). These give $e^i\pi$ or $e^(i\pi)$ respectively. (But use normal brackets in your *working*, for example e^{(i\pi)} gives $e^{(i\pi)}$.)

Comment: (Also, be careful with your dollar signs - you've let one slip from in front of the \delta.)

Comment: @Adrien how do you say $C_2=a_1+a_2/2$? First of all $C_1=a_{1,1}$, then $C_2=\frac{1}{2}(a_{1,2}+a_{2,2})$ and so on.

Comment: I know ! The temperature is too high or I have not think since too much time and my brain is damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on the sequences themselves. Here is what I have thought.

$\forall\ i\in \mathbb{N},\ \forall \epsilon>0,\ \exists N_i\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ s.t. $$|a_{i,n}|<\epsilon$$ for all $n\geq N_i$. Then let $N=\max_{i\in \mathbb{N}}N_i$. Now $\mathbf{IF}\ N<\infty$ then we see that $$|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^na_{i,n}|\leq\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{i,n}|<\epsilon$$ for all $n\geq N$, and consequently the sequence $c_n$ converges to $0$. But it does not seem obvious that the $\mathbf{IF}$ always holds.